# How to prevent older versions of the TLS protocl in python openssl client

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I need my python TLS client to offer only version TLS 1.2 (disable TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, SSLv3, SSLV2).

I am using python 3.6.5 and the openssl library under Windows 10. According to the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3), these two lines should prevent TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1:

> ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
>
> Prevents a TLSv1 connection. This option is only applicable in conjunction with PROTOCOL_TLS. It prevents the peers from choosing
>   TLSv1 as the protocol version.
>
> New in version 3.2.
>
> ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
>
> Prevents a TLSv1.1 connection. This option is only applicable in conjunction with PROTOCOL_TLS. It prevents the peers from choosing
>   TLSv1.1 as the protocol version. Available only with openssl version
>   1.0.1+.
>
> New in version 3.4.

And the above doucumentation says they are only applicable with the newly introduced:

```
PROTOCL_TLS
```

However, in practice, I tried to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 and test connecting to a TLS 1.0 (ONLY version supported in the test server) and my script still able to connect to it.

Am I doing something wrong? how the above two lines syntax in using them in conjunction with `PROTOCOL_TLS`?

This is the script I'm running:

```
import socket, ssl


context = ssl.SSLContext()

context.protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS  
context.protocol = ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 # prevents TLS 1.0
context.protocol = ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 # prevents TLS 1.1

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#note: the IP below is for private testing server not a public address
sslSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = '192.168.56.7')
sslSocket.connect((domain, 443))

print("connection succeeded")
sslSocket.close()
```

**NOTE:** for testing a live TLS 1.0 server, you can find any TLS 1.0 server by searching or use this [link](https://tls-v1-0.badssl.com:1010/) but I think they are using a different port than 443.

**NOTE:** I did not add:  `ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2` nor  `ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3`because they are disabled by default when using `context.protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for SSLContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.protocol) clearly states:

> SSLContext.protocol
>   The protocol version chosen when constructing the context. This attribute is **read-only**.

Thus, any attempts to set the protocol using this attribute will fail. Instead you need to modify the [SSLContext.options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.options):

```
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
```